# iPhoto printing PDFs sideways

Tags: mac, pdf, printing, iphoto

When I print to PDF from iPhoto (7.1.5), my scans (which are all portrait) all end up sideways in the PDF file. I've searched high and low for some setting that will alter this. The only one that I could find that would plausibly affect this is the Layout menu item in the Print customisation view, but this has no effect. Even rotating the images doesn't change it.

Why is iPhoto printing my PDFs sideways, and how do I get it to stop?

Answer (score 0):

Well... If it's a bug, I can't seem to replicate it in iPhoto 8.1.2, so updating might help. In either case, iPhoto is really designed to work with photo-sized images, which generally don't exist in a portrait format. Preview itself has different behavior that I think will do what you want, so if nothing else works, just drag the images you want to print to PDF out of iPhoto, open them all in Preview, and print to PDF from there.